# Recover accidentally deleted folder Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

I am using a VMWare to work on ubuntu, and Sunday's afternoon, I had the first error and when I was trying to solve it, I've accidentally deleted the var folder. This is the folder where I have all my projects stored, and i have no backup for it. Now I am getting a new kind of error with ubuntu. I don't exactly know what it is about, but since the first error I can't come to the login screen, I am doing everything now in the recovery mode terminal. What I want is to recover the folder I deleted, I can after that install another ubuntu and paste that folder in it it will be not a problem. Can anybody please help me?
I have tried a lot of things but each time I try to run a command it says that some files are missing, or that I need to run `apt get update/apt-get install`, but when I try to run it I get some errors also. More about the errors can be found in the imgs below. Sorry but I am not able to copy or show more description about the errors [image: apt get update] [image: Trying to recover deleted file] [image: Error message while starting up] [image: First problem]

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but your data is almost certainly lost forever.

I assume you are using a ext4 file-system since it is the default for Ubuntu. It is true that if you delete a folder and the files therein, some of the file contents may remain on disk. However, the i-nodes are marked as "unused" and are likely to be repurposed quickly. That means the data-structures which contain meta-information such as the directory names, file names, ownership information and the permissions can be lost after only a short time. This happens sooner if the file-system is being used – which is precisely what happened when you tried to recover the files from within the machine.

The most sensible thing you can do now is to move on. Keep it in mind as a lesson. In the future, create backups of important data in regular intervals.

On a side-note: If something like this happens to you, freeze the system immediately (this is easier done with a VM than a real machine). Then use a tool like `testdisk` from an external machine (e.g. the VM host). There may or may not be ways for cooler rescue methods such as accessing the journal, but I have not read about real-world success stories.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get your files back.

Create regular backups.

To keep from making the same mistake in the future, I recommend creating a "trash" directory and making an alias in `bash_aliases` to set `rm` to move "deleted" files to the trash folder.

Comment: Moving all of `/var` into `~root/.trash` very possibly will fail if var is of any significant size. Real lesson is not to run a root if you don't have. to.

Comment: @doneal24 I just moved `/var` into `/root/` on a VM which has both directories on the same partition, so it worked and took less than 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I would not recommend this alias for another reason: The user might get used to having it, but one day they end up on a machine without such a safety net. External backups are the way to go.